# Bootstrap 4 Grid not working inside UL

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, dropdown

I am trying to create a mega dropdown menu with bootstrap 4 grid system, whatever i did to the col, it just not float side by side. please give me a light! thanks

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container-fluid" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li id="menu-item-24" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Borrow</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu row">
                        <li class="col-sm-3 ">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menu-item-29" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">0</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" col-sm-3 ">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menu-item-49" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" col-sm-3 ">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menu-item-52" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class=" col-sm-3 ">
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menu-item-55" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Hello can you create a codepen/jsfiddle for this? I tried creating a pen but I don't know your resources so I can't replicate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This Css And Define Fixed Width**

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
display: flex;
}
```

**fixed width dropdown-menu**

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
min-width: 900px !important;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, it also works if i use float:left on all li child. wondering why its not working without extra code? thanks for your help.